# Make Flippy links available in page.html.twig (Drupal 8)

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8, drupal-templates

Using the [Flippy Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flippy) I would like to make the links that it prints in its theme file available in **page.html.twig** because I want to print them in a different region from where the node content gets printed.

The module states: "*If you turn on Flippy for a content type, but hide the pager in the Manage Display page, its links will still be available in the theme layer when it comes time to output node.tpl.php*"

That's correct, using Devel Module [enter link description here](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) I used `dpm(content)` on my `node.html.twig`template.

[image]

Doing `{{ content.flippy_pager}}` allows me to print the links, but it's all **within** `node.html.twig`.

How could I possible pass that information on to `page.html.twig` since my goal is to print it in a different region from where the node's main content gets printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module provides a "Flippy" block.

Go to the "Block layout page", click "Place block" for the region you want and add the "Flippy Block" block.